# Caliburn.Micro: create a borderless window with IWindowManager using WPF

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Using the [IWindowManager](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Window%20Manager) of [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com), is it possible to create a borderless window using the `ShowWindow` method?

In this case, the content of the Window is generated from a UserControl. And Caliburn.Micro will create a Window to host the UserControl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: The status today:**

With the current Caliburn.Micro v1.2 (July 20, 2011) release it's not possible to set properties on the created window. You can inherit from the `WindowManager` and override the `CreateWindow` method:

```
public class BorderlessWindowManager : WindowManager
{
    protected override Window CreateWindow(object rootModel, bool isDialog, 
       object context)
    {
        var window = base.CreateWindow(rootModel, isDialog, context);
        window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        window.AllowsTransparency = true;
        window.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        return window;
    }
}
```

**When the new version released:**

Yes it's possible, with the `settings` parameter:

```
public interface IWindowManager
{
    //...
    void ShowWindow(object rootModel, object context = null, 
         IDictionary<string, object> settings = null);
}
```

Caliburn.Micro will use this dictionary as `[property name; property value]` bag and set them on the created window with reflection.
I've never created a borderless window but based on this [artice](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/12/creating-border-less-windows-in-wpf.aspx) something like this should work:

```
windowManger.ShowWindow(viewModel, 
    settings: new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "WindowStyle", WindowStyle.None},
        { "ShowInTaskbar", false},
        { "AllowsTransparency", true},
        { "Background", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)},
    });
```

Comment: We are using the latest release v1.2 (July 20, 2011). It appears the settings parameter is in a newer, unreleased version. We could download the source and use the latest release, but we would like to only use the officially released version.

Comment: Oh.. sorry I've checked it directly in the source on CodePlex. I didn't know that it isn't released yet. I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm going to look into the latest WindowManger class for Caliburn Micro and see if there are any other new dependencies. If not, we'll probably just grab the source and implement that until the new version. But, will wait to see if you come up with an option for the v1.2 release first.

Comment: Can you depict where in the Solution tree the 'windowmanager.ShowWindow' method is located?

Comment: @Berlioz the `IWindowManager` is a part of Caliburn.Micro here is a [good article](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/) about it's usage. You can find also some sample projects in the [Caliburn.Micro source](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Window%20Manager&referringTitle=Documentation)